# Why am I getting an empty array when using an url for pull request comments?

Tags: github-api

Based on [official](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/comments?apiVersion=2022-11-28) GitHub this is the format to get comments on a pull request -

```
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/comments
```

Therefore I used the following url -

```
https://api.github.com/repos/RobotLocomotion/drake/pulls/18431/comments
```

For some reason, it doesn't work. I know that the above link does contain a pull request because this is not empty-

```
https://api.github.com/repos/RobotLocomotion/drake/pulls
```

Also the corresponding html url does have comments -

```
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/18933
```

Why do I get an empty array with the first link?

Answer (score 1):

I tried and cloned the repository, then used [`gh pr -c view 18431`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view).

I do see the comments.
Using `GH_DEBUG=API`, I can see the GitHub CLI is using a [GraphQL API V4](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) call:

GraphQL query:

```json
query PullRequestByNumber($owner: String!, $repo: String!, $pr_number: Int!) {
    repository(owner: $owner, name: $repo) {
      pullRequest(number: $pr_number) {url,number,title,state,body,author{login,...on User{id,name}},isDraft,maintainerCanModify,mergeable,additions,deletions,commits{totalCount},baseRefName,headRefName,headRepositoryOwner{id,login,...on User{name}},headRepository{id,name},isCrossRepository,reviewRequests(first: 100) {nodes {requestedReviewer {__typename,...on User{login},...on Team{organization{login}name,slug}}}},reviews(first: 100) {nodes {id,author{login},authorAssociation,submittedAt,body,state,commit{oid},reactionGroups{content,users{totalCount}}}pageInfo{hasNextPage,endCursor}totalCount},assignees(first:100){nodes{id,login,name},totalCount},labels(first:100){nodes{id,name,description,color},totalCount},projectCards(first:100){nodes{project{name}column{name}},totalCount},milestone{number,title,description,dueOn},comments(first: 100) {nodes {id,author{login,...on User{id,name}},authorAssociation,body,createdAt,includesCreatedEdit,isMinimized,minimizedReason,reactionGroups{content,users{totalCount}},url,viewerDidAuthor},pageInfo{hasNextPage,endCursor},totalCount},reactionGroups{content,users{totalCount}},createdAt,statusCheckRollup: commits(last: 1) {nodes {commit {statusCheckRollup {contexts(first:100) {nodes {__typename...on StatusContext {context,state,targetUrl,createdAt},...on CheckRun {name,checkSuite{workflowRun{workflow{name}}},status,conclusion,startedAt,completedAt,detailsUrl}},pageInfo{hasNextPage,endCursor}}}}}},id}
    }
  }
```

GraphQL variables:

```json
{"owner":"RobotLocomotion","pr_number":18431,"repo":"drake"}
```

That is a workaround of the [V3 API List review comments on a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/comments?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-review-comments-on-a-pull-request):

```bash
gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  /repos/RobotLocomotion/drake/pulls/18431/comments
```

That API call does return an empty array.